# Where is Athiss located?

Tags: star-wars

I've found several notes of where Athiss is located but I did not manage to find it on any map of the Star Wars universe (I know that planet is a part of the Loro Babis system).

Does it appear on any of the maps of the Galaxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Star Wars : Essential Atlas](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Essential-Daniel-Wallace/dp/1848562764) places Athiss as one of the core worlds of the Sith Empire (circa 5000BBY). It is positioned in the upper right quadrant of the known galaxy, about halfway around the outer rim.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Thomas - Not in that level of detail, I'm afraid. It would be unbelievably crowded, even at 2000x2000. I suggest you grab yourself a copy of the Essential Atlas if you want to locate a specific system. Note also that the overwhelming majority of these systems are no longer canon, nor is the "Essential Atlas" despite being being a Del Rey published book.

Comment: I'm planing on using the maps in an rpg campaign so the no longer canon part is not that much of a problem. tnx for mentioning the essential atlas there!